# creating tasks in cypress.config.js is not working

Tags: cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I have a task like this in `cypress.config.js`

```js
async function setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  allureWriter(on, config);
  await preprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);
  on('task', { downloadFile });
  on(
      "file:preprocessor",
      createBundler({
          plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin.default(config)],
      })
  );
  on("file:preprocessor", browserify.default(config));

  on('task', {
      log(message) {
          console.log(message)
          return null
      }
  });
  on('task', {
    createExcelFile(filePath, headers, data) {
      const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
      const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Sheet 1');

      if (headers && Array.isArray(headers)) {
            worksheet.addRow(headers);
            console.log('Header Row:', headers);
        }

        // Add data rows if data is provided
          if (data && Array.isArray(data)) {
                data.forEach(row => {
                worksheet.addRow(row);
                console.log('Data Row:', row);
            });
          }


      // Save the workbook to the specified file path
      return workbook.xlsx.writeFile(filePath)
        .then(() => {
            return null; // Indicate that the task was handled
        })
        .catch(error => {
            throw error; // Propagate the error if encountered
        });
      }
  });

  return config;
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  reporterOptions: {
      charts: true,
      reportPageTitle: "custom-title",
      embeddedScreenshots: true,
      inlineAssets: true,
      saveAllAttempts: false,
  },
  e2e: {
      setupNodeEvents,
 ----
 }

    }
  }
});
```

And I am calling this `createExcelFile` like this

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('createImportDemoExcel', () => {
  cy.fixture('testData/api/demo-api').then(call => {
    cy.request('GET', callPath
    ).then(function (res) {
      const apiResponse = res.body.data;
      const extractedData = [];

      apiResponse.forEach(item => {
        const age = item.id;
        const name = item.name;
        const zip = item.yearLevelId;
        extractedData.push([name, age, zip]);
      });

      const excelFilePath = "cypress/fixtures/testData/ImportData.xlsx";
      let headers = ['Age', 'Name', 'Zip'];
      cy.task('createExcelFile', excelFilePath, headers, extractedData);

      localStorage.setItem('token', res.body.token);
      localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', res.body.refreshToken);
    });
  });
});
```

But it is giving error as `Header Row: undefined` and `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')`. However the `extractedData.push([name, age, zip]);` is generated fine.

Also if I `cy.request` from config file within `createExcelFile` then there is no error but if I call it from commands.js then it gives `undefined`  error for `extractedData` and `headers`

What wrong am I doing?

Comment: Which foreach is causing the error?

Comment: The one that adds the rows to the data, this one `data.forEach(row => {
`

Comment: Thing is, you have `if (data && Array.isArray(data))` so `data` cannot be undefined.

Comment: `extractedData` is passed to it when I call it via `command.js`. So to confirm that `extractedData` is not blank/undefined I tried to print it in console and it printed the right data. Does `undefine` mean, it is not defined and I need to initialize it in `task` block itself?

Comment: Even if I remove `if` block, then also it gives the error that data.forEach can not be executed on undefined. BTW, are you able to reproduce it?

Comment: That is a very confused question.

Comment: Why would you remove the if block?

Comment: @MuffyCound if I don't want to check the condition `if (data && Array.isArray(data)) {` I will remove it.

Comment: @MuffyCound question is if `headers` and `extractedData` are not empty, properly defined then why they never reach inside `if` block? If I prepare the data (headers, extractedData) for if blocks within the `createExcelFile` task block then it passes. Were you able to reproduce it? Is it working for you, from `command.js`?

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned, the code in the task can't be causing the error

```js
if (data && Array.isArray(data)) {
  data.forEach(row => {                    <--------- data cannot be undefined
```

so it must be this code

```js
apiResponse.forEach(item => {
```

which means you are not extracting the response correctly.

Try parsing

```js
cy.request('GET', callPath)
  .then(res => {
    const apiResponse = JSON.parse(res.body.data)
```

or else examine what the response is and adjust accordingly.

There isn't enough information to say exactly, because you jumped to the wrong conclusion. In fact, the error has nothing to do with the task!